# Problema con Route reactjs al subirlo a hosting

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

tengo mi proyecto de React.js ya funcionando perfectamente (al menos en local) y listo para subir, pero tengo un problema con las rutas, esta es mi app:

```
    <Router>
  <Navbar />
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/contacto">
      <Contacto />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/explicacion">
      <Explication />
    </Route>
    <Route path="/">
      <div className="pa4">
        <Search details={initialDetails}/>
      </div>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

en Localhost esas rutas funcionan y se ven correctamente de la siguiente manera:

```
      <Button color="inherit" href="/explicacion">Como funciona</Button>
      <Button color="inherit" href="/contacto">Contactanos</Button>
```

ese Button es de material ui, y están colocados en el en Navbar. Al correr npm run build me crea la app lista para subirla al hosting, comprimo, subo al hosting, descomprimo y se ve perfectamente la pagina principal, pero al hacer click en contacto y en explicacion, indica que no existe esa ruta y no se puede ver. Que podria ser? el hosting es 000webhost.

Gracias a todos

Comment: Hola amigo, ¿ya configuraste un archivo .htaccess en el root de tu aplicación?

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta, la verdad en el hosting habia ya uno cargado, pero yo manualmente no configuré nada, investigaré eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude solucionarlo, es un error común al cargar el proyecto de react.js a un servidor apache (cpanel en este caso), en el documento .htaccess solo tuve que escribir lo siguiente:

```
  RewriteEngine On  
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  RewriteRule ^ /index.html [L]
```

gracias a JCAguilera por darme una pista donde buscar!